# Validating html-javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, validation

When I press the Submit Button, error does not show. I have used Internet Explorer and Google Chrome too.

I am trying to do a Form Validation page for my MySQL database.

Maybe my alert code is false?

This is my Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Validare</title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function ver() {
                if (document.form1.name.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu numele");
                    return false;
                }
                If(document.form1.email.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu e-mail-ul")
                    return false;
                }
                if (document.form1.age.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Varsta");
                    document.form1.age.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (document.form1.age.value < 18 || document.form1.age.value > 60) {
                    alert("Te rog introdu adresa cuprinsa in intevalul[18,60] ");
                    document.form1.age.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                If(document.form1.gender[0].checked == false && document.form1.gender[1].checked == false) {
                    alert("Te rog alege Sex-ul");
                    document, form1.age.focus();
                    return flase;
                }
                If(docuemnt.form1.limba1.checked == false && document.form1.limba2.checked == false && document.form1.limba3.checked == false) {
                    alert("Te rog selecteaza cel putin o limba");
                    return false;
                }
                if (document.form1.country.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Tara");
                    document.form1.country.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                If(document.form1.myadress.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Adresa");
                    document.form1.myadress.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if (document.form1.u_name.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Username");
                    document.form1.u_name.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                If(document.form1.pass.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Password")
                    document.form1.pass.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                If(document.form1.pass.value.length < 6) {
                    alert("Te rog introdu Password mai lunga ca 6");
                    document.form1.pass.focus();
                    return false;
                }
                If(document.form1.r_pass.value == "") {
                    alert("Te rog introdu din nou parola");
                    document.form1.r_pass.focus();
                    terun false;
                }
                If((document.form1.pass.value) != (document.form1.r_pass.value)) {
                    alert("Password-ul nu se potriveste");
                    document.form1.r_pass.value = "";
                    document.form1.r_pass.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="" name="form1">
            <table border="2" align="center" cellpadding="7" cellspacin="7">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Nume</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>E-Mail</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="email">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Varsta</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="age" size="2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Sex</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Masculin
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Feminin</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Limba</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="limba1" value="Romana">Romana
                        <input type="checkbox" name="limba2" value="Engleza">Engleza
                        <input type="checkbox" name="limba3" value="Germana">Germana</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Tara</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="country">
                            <option value="selected">-Selecteaza-
                                <option value="Germ">Germania
                                    <option value="roman">Romania
                                        <option value="ungar">Ungaria</select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Adresa</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="myadress"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Username</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="u_name">
                </tr>
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Password</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="pass">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Re-Type</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="r_pass">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return ver(this);">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="reset">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? If this is copy-paste then you need to check for typos (`terun`)

Comment: it's not copy paste.I'm using Notepad++ how can i start a debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the onclick handler from the submit and place a sumbit handler on the form element.

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" onsubmit="return ver(this);">
```

Also you didn't define an action, so no posting will be done to a server side page. Second here a typo

```
            If(document.form1.r_pass.value == "") {
                alert("Te rog introdu din nou parola");
                document.form1.r_pass.focus();
                terun false; //SHOULD BE return false;
            }

            If(document.form1.gender[0].checked == false && document.form1.gender[1].checked == false) {
                alert("Te rog alege Sex-ul");
                document, form1.age.focus();
                return flase; //SHOULD be return false;
            }
```

I think there are a lot more typos and other coding errors. Use keyboard key <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser, that will open up the console (dev tools) which gives you information about the errors.

Comment: It works now,if I press the submit button without filling the Nume textbox,it shows me the alert.Only first alert is shown the others not?Why

Comment: Because you are using `return false`. It ends the function there.

Comment: If you want to work with alerts, this is the best way, else you overflow the user with alerts, else you can set a message at every input. Do some Google searching, you'll find lots of examples.